# How to query and count and count distinct at the same time?

Tags: mysql, h2

```
SELECT * FROM UserTable limit 100 ORDER BY userID ASC offset 0 ROWS;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserTable;
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email) FROM UserTable;
```

How to combine it all into one query?

Expected output should be something like

```
totalCount    distinctCount    userID    email ...
100000        1000             1         qwerty@qwerty.com
100000        1000             2         qwerty@qwerty.com
100000        1000             3         abc.abc.com
...
```

Comment: It is mysql database

Comment: No. I use a variety of databases.

Comment: Tell us the output you want.  You haven't posted a complete question (despite what you may think).

Comment: Okay, I have edited the question. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little bit curious on processing speed here, could you comment every working query with how many second did it take (with the same data loading) ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cross join on the count subquery

```
  SELECT t.totalCount, t.distinctCount, UserTable.* 
  FROM UserTable 
  cross join (
    SELECT COUNT(*)  totalCount, COUNT(DISTINCT email) as distinctCount
    FROM UserTable
  ) t 
  ORDER BY userID ASC limit 100
```

Answer (score 1):

here you are:

```
    select 
(select count(*) from UserTable a) as count,
(select count(DISTINCT quarter) from UserTable b) as distinctCount,
c.* from UserTable as c order by userID ASC limit 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a group by:

Try following query:

SELECT * FROM UserTable limit 100 ORDER BY userID ASC offset 0 ROWS GROUP BY email

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it using subquery Join in MySQL:

```
SELECT UserTable.*, tc.totalCount, dc.distinctCount
FROM UserTable 
JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as totalCount
    FROM UserTable
) tc
JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT email) as distinctCunt
    FROM UserTable
) dc
ORDER BY userID ASC 
LIMIT 100
```